# How to pass device token to PCL from Android MainActivity?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, google-cloud-messaging

I have added code in MainActivity.cs file for generating Device Id. Now I want to pass that device token to my PCL project main page, How's that possible? I also want to know about how to generate Device Token in IOS app? and how to pass that token to Portable Class Library?

Code Sample :

```
 public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());
        if (Intent.Extras != null)
        {
            foreach (var key in Intent.Extras.KeySet())
            {
                var value = Intent.Extras.GetString(key);
                Log.Debug("Key: {0} Value: {1}", key, value);
            }
        }
        FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this);
        var instanceId = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance;
        if (FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token != null)
            Log.Debug("MyToken", FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token.ToString());            
    }
}
```

I need this "My Token" data on login page button Click event. Hows this possible?

My Login Page Code is

```
 public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly DataService _dataService = new DataService();
    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private async Task BtnLogin_ClickedAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var result = await _dataService.Authentication(TxtUserName.Text, TxtPassword.Text,"MyToken");
        if (result.AccessToken != null)
        {
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainMasterPage());
            GlobalClass.userToken = result;
        }
        else
            await DisplayAlert("", Resource.InvalidMessage, Resource.OkText);

    }
}
```

Comment: Try this http://codeworks.it/blog/?p=260

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the Realm of **Dependency Injection** :)

[documentation can be found here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/dependency-injection/)

You need to create a interface on your PCL then reference that on your Native project

Example: 
Create class DeviceToke.cs in your PCL

```
public interface ITextToSpeech
{
    void Speak(string text);
}
```

Then in your native project, you can do the following:

sample code:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(TextToSpeechAndroidImpl))]
namespace IocAndDiXamarinForms.Droid
{
    public class TextToSpeechAndroidImpl : Java.Lang.Object, ITextToSpeech, TextToSpeech.IOnInitListener
    {
        TextToSpeech speaker;
        string toSpeak;

        public void Speak(string text)
        {
            var ctx = Forms.Context; // useful for many Android SDK features
            toSpeak = text;
            if (speaker == null)
            {
                speaker = new TextToSpeech(ctx, this);
            }
            else
            {
                var p = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                speaker.Speak(toSpeak, QueueMode.Flush, p);
            }
        }

        #region IOnInitListener implementation
        public void OnInit(OperationResult status)
        {
            if (status.Equals(OperationResult.Success))
            {
                var p = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                speaker.Speak(toSpeak, QueueMode.Flush, p);
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the Xamarin messaging center](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/) to pass a message back from your platform-specific classes to your PCL ViewModel. You'll need to subscribe to the message in your VM, and send the message from your Android or iOS class. Then you can store the value in your VM and use it when the user clicks login.

Sending the message:

```
Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send(FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token.ToString(), "InstanceId");
```

Subscribing in your VM:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string> (this, "InstanceId", (InstanceId) => {
            // use the InstanceId as required
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

A handy solution is to define a publicly accessible static `StrToken` property in some public class, e.g.  `App`:

```
public static Size Token;
```

and OnCreate on Android:

```
App.StrToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance;
```